# Unable to change a value inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a project that I took over with the input reads from a barcode, currently iam having trouble with my output giving me a fix value which the code reads from and does not read from the actual input.

below is the html code for the scanner. it reads fine

```
<div class="section" id="instruction-3">
            <p>Otherwise, scan your code at the bottom, or manually type it in here:</p>
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="IC-input" name="IC" onclick="openKeyboard()" onkeyup="autofill(this.value)" placeholder="Enter your IC Number" required maxlength="9">
                <label><button type="button" id="theButton" onclick="theButtonIsPressed()">Submit</button></label>
            </span>
        </div>
```

follow by the javascript (which i suspect is where the problem lies but am not sure)

```
<script>
    var NRIC = '{"NRIC":"0"}'; 

    function theButtonIsPressed(){
        closeKeyboard();
        console.log('button clicked');
        NRIC = '{"NRIC":"123456789"}';
        //var IcNum = document.getElementById("IC-input").value;
        //NRIC = NRIC.replace("0", IcNum);
        document.getElementById("IC-input").value = "";
        doWork(NRIC)
    }
</script>   

        function doWork(NRIC) {
        // ajax the JSON to the server
        $.post("receiver", NRIC, function(){
        });
        // stop link reloading the page

function update() {
        setInterval(function(){$.post("receiver", '{"NRIC":NRIC}', function(){});}, 900);
```

It keeps giving me the value inside NRIC = '{"NRIC":"123456789"}'; which is 123456789, i realize this might be a simple fix but i am still learning and am unsure.

thank you in advance.

Comment: the question is not clear to me

Comment: Currently when i input a barcode it is giving me the fix value inside the { }, no matter what i tried to fix it, it either won't give me any output or only the value 123456789 from '{"NRIC":"123456789"}'; like i mention so i am hoping some one can help with this.

Comment: `'{"NRIC":NRIC}'` makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all but I have solved the problem, it was my fault that I did not mention I wanted to transfer the data to another webpage, and the problem with that was that the data was not transferred over to the other html.

```
function autofill(value){
        console.log("Autofill:"+value)
        //console.log(9 digits);
        button = document.getElementById("theButton");
        if(value.length == 9){
            console.log('form is ready to submit');
            theButtonIsPressed(value);
        } 
    }


    function theButtonIsPressed(value){ 
        closeKeyboard();
        console.log('button clicked');
        //NRIC = '{"NRIC":"123456789"}';
        console.log(value)
        doWork(value)
    }
```

by doing this it read the value as accordingly from the input and worked after, sorry again for my confusing question and thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understanded you want to have in the obj the input value, so try this:

```
function theButtonIsPressed(){
    closeKeyboard();
    console.log('button clicked');
    var IcNum = document.getElementById("IC-input").value;
    NRIC.NRIC = IcNum;
    doWork(NRIC)
}
```

Comment: Yes! that is my problem, i just tried your code and now it's giving me the "0" as a output, iam assuming from  var NRIC = '{"NRIC":"0"}'; , any solution for this as well? thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you edit with the new code? Thanks 

PS. remember no quotes around object

Answer (score 0):

Why quotes around an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)?

```
var NRIC = {"NRIC": 0}; 
function theButtonIsPressed() {
  NRIC = {"NRIC": 123456789};
  doWork(NRIC)
}
```

Comment: This project was passed on to me and i was wondering the same thing but iam almost if not entirely new to html/Java so iam unsure as well but will removing the quotes fix the problem?

Comment: I think so. The string is built like an object, so that's what I figured. Try reading the docs for more info on objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Unfortunately removing the quotes did not fix it, tysm for taking your time to reply though.

Comment: Perhaps if you provide the code for the function `doWork()`, or at least a minimal reproducible example, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: My apologies, i have added in the `dowork()`  function onto the question, do let me know if anything else is missing thank you.